# .htaccess rewrite url , dont work on Form Submit

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am working on a search display, but got some problems with the htaccess, not working the way I want it to. I got multiple rewrites on the same url and I assume thats why. But i am not sure..

---

**UPDATE**: From what I can see by testing, all the Rewrite urls work. But the form force the page over to `search.php?search=test` and not `search/test` as i want.

So the real question is:

> How do I get form action="" to submit to search/test/ and not search.php?search=test

---

**What i get:**

```
search.php?page=1
search.php?type=DEFINED_TYPE&search=test
search.php?type=DEFINED_TYPE&search=test&page=1
```

**What i want:**

```
search/1
search/DEFINED_TYPE/test
search/DEFINED_TYPE/test/1
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="" method="get" id="searchForm">

<label for="DEFINED_TYPE_radio">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="DEFINED_TYPE_radio" value="DEFINED_TYPE"<?php if($_GET['type'] == 'DEFINED_TYPE') echo ' checked' ?> />
    <em<?php if($_GET['type'] == 'DEFINED_TYPE') echo ' class="selected"' ?>><i class="fas fa-tags"></i>Type</em>
</label>

<div class="input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." value="<?php echo isset($_GET['search']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']) : '' ?>" name="search" id="searchField" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <i class="fa fa-search submit" id="submit"></i>
</div>

</form>
```

**Htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^search$                    search.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)$            search.php?page=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$            search.php?type=$1&search=$2 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$   search.php?type=$1&search=$2&page=$3 [E=ORIG_URI:/$1]
```

Anyone who can spot what I do wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: @starkeen Look at "What is want" vs. "What i get" on form submit.

Comment: Do you want  to type `search.php?page=1` in your browser  and see `/search/1` ?

Comment: @starkeen When i submit the form, it goes to search.php/page=1 and not search/1 as i told the htaccess to do.

Comment: @starkeen - this has to do with routing and the setup in the .htaccess file(s) when a user types a path, do you know about that topic and how to set that up?

Comment: Updated the question, to be more detailed.

Comment: note that as you are using get method on the form, every field is added with its name to the url as a param

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Is there a way edit the outcome, in the url? So it looks neat. Because, i cant use $_POST for it, because of a pagination. (Or maybe I can, but idk how :-))

Comment: Your htaccess rules only handle the clean urls ie `/search/1` . When you enter `/search/1` your rule rewrites it to `/search.php?page=1` . You need to use an additional 301 redirect rule to redirect the old url to the new url format ie `/search.php?page=1` to `/search/1` .

Answer (score 0):

Note that as you are using get method on the form, every field is added with its name to the url as a param.

I suggest you submit the form with method post and add the url in the action attribute (or the whole url):

```
<form action="search.php?search=test" method="post" id="searchForm">
```

or

```
<form action="/search/test" method="post" id="searchForm">
```

> That involves changing how you read those values